# How to zip audio files before downloading in wp8 same as Google Drive

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am downloading several audio files one by one using `BackgroundTransferRequest` and the some of the downloads could be upto 70 MB. I am thinking of zipping these audio files before downloading (the same when downloading multiple files from Google drive).

Just to make it clear, I don't want to store zip files in Isolated storage, I just need to compress audio files in the fly and then download the zipped version using `BackgroundTransferRequest` and finally decompress it.

1. Is it possible to Zip audio files before downloading in wp8?
2. Do I need third party tool for it or .Net provide compression / decompression classes for it?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried manually zipping the files? I think you'd find that compressing audio files won't do very much good.

Comment: Thanks, I have searched regarding compressing / decompressing in wp8 and I find useful links for compressing / decompressing files, but what I want is to compress in the fly the same as Google Drive does. If you select two files to download from Google Drive, It automatically compresses them (creates a zip file) and then downloads that zip file.

Comment: That's a feature of Google Drive then, so, as Mangist wrote, to be able to do that the server you're downloading from needs to do the compression for you.

Comment: Do you mean that Google Drive does this compressing and saves the zipped version somewhere in it's server?

Comment: Something like that yes. To zip them yourself, you'd need to download the files first.

Answer (score 0):

You can't zip something you haven't downloaded yet, unless you're downloading it from your own web service?

If you are, .NET provides the GZipCompression classes to handle ZIP files.

Comment: Thanks, I ask you, If you have time please check this feature in Google Drive. If you select two files to download, It automatically compress both files into one zip file and then downloads that file. I don't see the zipped file in my Google Drive when downloading it.

Comment: Google drive does all the zipping on the server. You won't have control of that. Even if you did, the entire point of audio formats is that they highly compress the data, so the space difference would be very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ionic.Zip library for making zip-files:

here is an example to zip a file:

```
 string audiofile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

 using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
      {
        using (MemoryStream tempstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
          string fileName = "song.mp3";
          string filepath = audiofile + "song.mp3";
          byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);

          zipFile.AddEntry(fileName, fileBytes);
        }
      }
      Guid g = new Guid();
      g = Guid.NewGuid();
      string path = audiofile + "Temp\\" + g.ToString() + ".Zip";
      zipFile.Save(path);

     // RETURN FILE USING YOUR BACKGROUNDTRANSFERREQUEST HERE with the path-variable 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, You are compressing from Base Directory but not from a URL (Don't know if it's possible with Ionic.ZIP) and then you are saving it in Temp directory inside Base Directory. I don't have this option to save files before downloading. (create zip in the fly and download the stream)